# Connection refused with maven + ant :

Tags: maven, ant

I'm trying to build Hadoop-24 on windows. 
Everything works fine when suddenly :

```
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HttpFS .............................. FAILURE [8.568s]
```

The associated error is this :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7: run (dist) on project hadoop-hdfs-httpfs: An Ant BuildException has occured: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<get dest="downloads/apache-tomcat-6.0.36.tar.gz" skipexisting="true" verbose="true" src="http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.36/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.36.tar.gz"/>... @ 5:182 in C:\hadoop-src\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs-httpfs\target\antrun\build-main.xml
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (dist) on project hadoop-hdfs-httpfs: An Ant BuildException has occured: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
around Ant part ...<get dest="downloads/apache-tomcat-6.0.36.tar.gz" skipexisting="true" verbose="true" src="http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0
.36/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.36.tar.gz"/>... @ 5:182 in C:\hadoop-src\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs-httpfs\target\antrun\build-main.xml
```

Everything seems to indicate a connexion error. However :

1. the other packages were downloaded without trouble (via Maven and Ant)
2. the proxy is well configured (see first point)
3. I can download the aforementioned file via firefox.

Right now, I dodged this problem by downloading manually the file and putting it where it's expected. However, I would like to understand why is this not working naturally. Would you folks see the reason why ?

Comment: It does not look like you proxy is correctly configured `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
around Ant part ...<get dest="downloads/apache-tomcat-6.0.36.tar.gz" skipexisting="true" verbose="true" src="http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0`

Comment: It is, that's what's strange (every other dependency is normally downloaded, only this one fails).

Comment: Maybe it's due to the size of the package downloaded, i've got file size restriction on my proxy and think it's the source of the problem.

Comment: After all, i don't think it came from the proxy file restriction 'cause i could download the package manually, as suggested in the original question

Answer (score 1):

It is due to the proxy settings. In theory, maven should check the settings.xml file under /.m2 but for some reason, the maven ant run plugin doesn't do that. So you have to specify it in the maven command like the one below

```
mvn package -Dhttp.proxyHost=<your proxy host> -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
```